# what is inlining merges when rebasing

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm reading [this article](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/getting-solid-at-git-rebase-vs-merge-4fa1a48c53aa) about `git rebase`, which contains the following passage:

> By default, a rebase will inline merges. As we now make sure our
>   merges have clear semantics in our history graph, this inlining is
>   real bummer...
>
> We can avoid this by telling rebase we want to preserve
>   merges: all we need to do is invoke it with `--preserve-merges` (or the
>   shorthand `-p`)

I don't understand what he means by *inlining*. Can you please provide an eloborate example so that I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [git-scm doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

> Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":
>
> ```
>       A---B---C topic
>      /
> D---E---F---G master From this point, the result of either of the following commands:
> ```
>
> git rebase master git rebase master topic would be:
>
> ```
>               A'--B'--C' topic
>              /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```

So, the `rebase` operation of branch `topic` on the base `master` takes all commits of `topic` who are not in master, resets the current state to `master`, and replays those commits one by one (asking the user to deal with inconsistencies along the way, which explains the commits `A'`, `B'` ... being potentially different from `A` `B` ..).

That same logic applies to a merge branch. As the image from your article shows:
[image: rebase example]

At the beginning, you have a local `master` which is a *merge commit* between master and the branch `origin/feature`. Then the user does a pull with rebase (`git pull -rebase`) which amounts to rebasing branch `master` on `origin/master`. At that stage, all the commits in `master` that aren't in `origin/master` are those in the *merged branch ancestor* of `master`, that is, the commits in `origin/feature`. The problem is that replaying those commits erases the fact that those where once an external branch which happens to have been merged in `master`.

That is, it's this `replay` that is the `inlining` that you're asking about. While it may be OK to do that kind of thing for a regular fork (the example from the doc above), it's problematic for merge information if it is what you use to keep track of where those commits came from (as in the article you link to).

Comment: thanks! so git will try to replay all commits starting from 80b0beb (first commit in feature branch) and not just one merge commit 2e6104b? I assumed that git will do `git diff` between the last commit on master branch and the commit on `origin/master` where branching occurred, no?

Comment: No, it will try to replay all commits contained in the {to-be-rebased} branch and not in the {root-of-rebase} branch, chronologically, of which the first will happen to be `80b0beb`. 

Operations based on a `git diff` are morally a `merge`, not a rebase – that's the whole point of the definition of `rebase`.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. As I've read git uses `git diff` to find differences between commits which then are applied as part of rebasing (in essence, cherry-picking), so I don't understand last sentence in your comment.

Comment: `merge` = a single `git diff` to reconcile things. `rebase` : one `git diff` per commit to see if it's present on the {root-of-rebase} branch. When I said "Operations based on a `git diff`", the important word I should have boldened is *a*.

Comment: I don't see merge commit applied after rebase, is it not applied because it is already in master branch?